# Obtaining an expectation in uniform hashing

Tags: probabilistic-algorithms, hashing

long shot question but I am super stuck.

Donald Knuth has proven (p. 8 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9503235.pdf), equation 12) that the probability that the maximum value in uniform hashing is smaller than $n/2$ is equal to 0.288. I wonder if with this information I can recover what is the expectation of the maximum value? Simulation strongly suggest 0.63 n but I would like to understand what I am doing.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to set up the problem in a self-contained way?  What is "uniform hashing", and what is "the maximum value in uniform hashing"?  What is $n$?  Also: Are you really asking "given only the probability that something is smaller than $n/2$, can I recover what is the expectation?"  Or are you asking "What is the expectation of this thing?  I know the probability that it is smaller than $n/2$."  I suggest being precise about what your question is.

Comment: No, you cannot derive the expectation of a random variable from the probability that it is at most $x$ for a single value of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that the maximum rank $r_{\max}$ is at most $m$ is
$$ (1 - q_{1m}) \cdots (1 - q_{nm}), $$
where
$$ q_{km} = \binom{k-1}{m} \bigg/ \binom{n}{m}. $$
Therefore
$$
\mathbb{E}[r_{\max}] = \sum_{m=1}^n \Pr[r_{\max} \geq m] =
\sum_{m=1}^n (1 - \Pr[r_{\max} \leq m-1]) = \\
1 + \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \left[1 - \prod_{k=1}^n \left(1 - \binom{k-1}{m}\bigg/\binom{n}{m}\right)\right].
$$
When $m = (1-\alpha) n$, the $m$'th summand is roughly equal to
$$ 1 - \prod_{i=1}^\infty (1-\alpha^i) = 1 - \phi(\alpha), $$
where $\phi(x)$ is the [Euler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function), and so
$$
\frac{\mathbb{E}[r_{\max}]}{n} \approx 1 - \int_0^1 \phi(x) \, dx = 1 - \frac{8\sqrt{3/23}\pi\sinh(\sqrt{23}\pi/6)}{2\cosh(\sqrt{23}\pi/3)-1} \approx 0.631587464068566.
$$

Comment: Super helpful, thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you have a reference for the integral of the Euler constant on [0,1] equal to the sinh expression? I read it on the Wikipedia article but no citation is provided either.

Comment: I took it from Wikipedia as well.

Comment: What does $m=(1-a)n$ even mean ? Would you kindly elaborate more ?

Comment: Same as defining $\alpha = 1 - m/n$.